# trying to move file to different location(in project folder)

Tags: java, file-io, javafx, fxml

I am trying to move file to project folder using this following code.  The code is getting the file from the user, however it is not moving to the new location.  Can someone please help me.  Thank you in advance

```
@FXML private void setNewPhotoButton(ActionEvent event){
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) newPhotoButton.getScene().getWindow();

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Choose an image");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif"));

        File f = new File("photos/");
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(f);
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(currentStage);

        if(selectedFile != null){
            //System.out.println("C:/" + selectedFile.getPath());
            //System.out.println("userfiles/"+UNAME+"/"+ANAME+"/");
            File src = new File(selectedFile.getPath());
            File dest = new File("userfiles/"+UNAME+"/"+ANAME+"/");
            Path sr = src.toPath();
            Path ds = new File(dest,src.getName()).toPath();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to move in to any resource folder of your project ?

Comment: yes i am @ViswanathLekshmanan

Comment: i figured it out thank you everyone for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, thank you everyone for helping.  Here's what I did

```
Path movefrom = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(selectedFile.getPath());
            Path target = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("userfiles/"+UNAME+"/"+ANAME+"/"+selectedFile.getName());
            Path targetDir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("userfiles/"+UNAME+"/"+ANAME);
            try{
                Files.move(movefrom,target,StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
            }catch (IOException e){}
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you are creating the new file *objects*, but aren't making the necessary changes on the disk. Once you have `selectedFile` chosen by the user, consider using the [`Files` class' move() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html).

Comment: I tried Files move class, but im getting some kind of error @entpnerd

Comment: try {
                Files.move(sr,ds,ATOMIC_MOVE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } @entpnerd

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
File src = new File("");
```

Without value between quotation marks file will be create in your project workspace.